# Dynamic table : setting the column number after the table

Tags: tables, cross-referencing, counters, programming, calculations

I would like to create a dynamic table with `\N` columns at the beginning of the page, in which `\N` is the number of sections in the whole document, so the value of `\N` is set *after* the table. When I set the value of `\N` before the table (in my example, moving line 26 `\N=\value{section}` after line 10 `\section{section 1}`), everything is alright, but when I set the value of `\N` after the table (as it is here in my example), this generates an error.

Here is my code, with the value of `\N` set after the table. I suppose it's not so difficult, but I couldn't find a solution. Does anyone have an idea?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newtoks\cols
\newcounter{i}
\newcount\N
\begin{document}
    \section{section 1}
\cols={}
\setcounter{i}{1}
\loop
\cols=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\cols\the\value{i}}
\ifnum\value{i}<\N
\cols=\expandafter{\the\cols &}
\stepcounter{i}
\repeat
\begin{tabular}{|*{\N}{c|}}
    \the\cols
\end{tabular}
\section{section 2}
\section{section 3}
\section{section 4}
\section{section 5}
\N=\value{section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, problems like this can be resolved by saving your table to **an external file** by the end of your document. All you need to do is to `\input` the external file in earlier part of the document. However, this does require one to compile the document twice for the table to be updated correctly. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
\section{section 1}
% load the table, if it exists
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.table}{}{}
\section{section 2}
\section{section 3}
\section{section 4}
\section{section 5}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% open external file for writing
\iow_open:Nn \g_tmpa_iow {\jobname.table}
% get number of sections
\int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int {\value{section}}
% write begin environment 
\iow_now:Nx \g_tmpa_iow {\c_backslash_str begin{tabular}
    {|*{\int_use:N \l_tmpa_int}{c|}}}
% write columns into a sequence
\seq_clear:N \l_tmpa_seq
% loop over integers and fill the sequence
\int_step_inline:nn {\l_tmpa_int} {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
}
% write table content
\iow_now:Nx \g_tmpa_iow {
    \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {~&~} % join the sequence with " & "
}
% write end environment
\iow_now:Nx \g_tmpa_iow {\c_backslash_str end{tabular}}
\iow_close:N \g_tmpa_iow
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I am more familiar with LaTeX3. I am sure you can use LaTeX2e code to achieve the same goal as well.

**Update: storing the number of sections in a variable**

If all you want is to store the number of sections in a variable, here is a simpler example. It writes the line `\global\def\numsection{5}` into the `aux` file, which can be accessed in the next run.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}
Number of sections: \numsection

\section{section 1}
\section{section 2}
\section{section 3}
\section{section 4}
\section{section 5}

\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\global\string\def\string\numsection{\the\value{section}}}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and example! However, I must say I was expecting something more simpler, like a counter or a variable for the number of sections, that would be set at the end of the document, and the document to be runned 2 times. Or maybe something like a `\label{mylastpage}`, and then `\ref{mylastpage}`? Or maybe like the `lastpage` package?

Comment: @Garulfo If you only want to store the number of sections in a variable, there is definitely a simpler solution. Please refer to the updates.

Comment: @ Alan Xiang Thank you so much!!! :-D This is exactly what I was expecting, end it solves definitely my problem! Thanks for your kind help! Robin (Garulfo)